# using assimp_cmd to dump fbx model file and render

Tags: assimp

I want to parse the FBX model files with assimp, firstly, I need to generate some *.json which including the whole FBX model file information, and then rendering it through webGL in browser.
So far, I know we can dump the information of a fbx file, it will generate a .assxml or a *.assbin, it seems that the generated file inlucding all the information of a FBX model file. I wonder if it's possible that I can converting the *.assxml or *.assbin to *.json as above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://github.com/assimp/assimp2json to solve this. There are plans to integrate this into assimp, but time is a really critical resource. So help is welcome :-).

Kim